# Python 3.x - Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, crash

I'm trying to create a miner game, but it crashes everytime. Can you help me? Here is my code:

```
def refill(event):
    for i in everything:
        c.delete(i) # This is the 'Delete' statement
        time.sleep(0.01)
        global x2
        global y2
        for i in range(10): # This is the 'Create' statement
            for i in range(10):
                if random.randint(1, IRON_CHANCE) != 1:
                    stone = c.create_rectangle(x2, y2, x2 + 50, y2 + 50, fill='dim gray')
                    everything.append(stone)
                    y2 += 50
                if random.randint(1, IRON_CHANCE) == 1:
                    ironStone = c.create_rectangle(x2, y2, x2 + 50, y2 + 50, fill='dim gray')
                    ironRect = c.create_rectangle(x2 + 10, y2 + 10, x2 + 40, y2 + 40, fill='ivory')
                    irons.append(ironRect)
                    everything.append(ironStone)
                    everything.append(ironRect)
                    y2 += 50
                    time.sleep(0.01)
            x2 += 50
            y2 = 0
            time.sleep(0.01)
```

I think the problem is in the 'Create' state. If I delete that state,
the game works smooth and fine. Can you please help me?

Comment: Is this your whole code? If not, please add some context.

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations. And we can't read in your mind nor see your screen (magic glass ball broke down)

Comment: using `sleep()` is not good idea - it stops `mainloop()` which gets mouse/key events from system, sends events to widgets, updates widgets, redraws widgets.  Better use `tk.after()` to execute function periodically

Answer (score 0):

Note that this statement

```
if random.randint(1, IRON_CHANCE) != 1:
```

can be equal to one, and the next if statement can not be equal to one at the same time, because you are using 2 different numbers.  Perhaps you want an else.  We can not help further without code that is more complete and the complete trackback from the error.

```
            if random.randint(1, IRON_CHANCE) != 1:
                stone = c.create_rectangle(x2, y2, x2 + 50, y2 + 50, fill='dim gray')
                everything.append(stone)
                y2 += 50
            else:
                ironStone = c.create_rectangle(x2, y2, x2 + 50, y2 + 50, fill='dim gray')
                ironRect = c.create_rectangle(x2 + 10, y2 + 10, x2 + 40, y2 + 40, fill='ivory')
                irons.append(ironRect)
etc
```